# Mysql Stored Procedure for insert plus update with where array

Tags: mysql

I Am trying to create stored procedure in MYsql where I am inserting some value in one table and updating some vale in other table with where clause in my where clause I am using array problem I am facing is that I am not able to use Array and normal values together

I tried below code which is not working

```
DELIMITER //

 CREATE PROCEDURE p_paymententry1

    (

       IN p_id     int(11),

       IN p_date     timestamp, 

       IN p_2000 int(11),

       IN p_500 int(11),

       IN p_200 int(11),

       IN p_100 int(11),

       IN p_50 int(11),

       IN p_20 int(11),

       IN p_10 int(11),

       IN p_11 VARCHAR(30)
   )


     BEGIN

         INSERT INTO paymententry_truck (Payment_ID, Date, `2000`, `500`, `200`, `100`, `50`, `20`, `10`)

         VALUES (p_id, p_date, p_2000, p_500, p_200, p_100, p_50, p_20, p_10 );

         UPDATE trans1 SET paidStatus = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE trans1.Sr_NO IN(p_11);

     END // 

     DELIMITER ;
```

then I called my procedure

```
CALL p_paymententry1 (NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '12', '1','1','1','','','6',15,17);
```

but its throwing error

> Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE t_freight.p_paymententry1; expected 10, got 11

how to handle this I want to enter array in My P_11 value so it can apply where clause to rows with value in array

Comment: Doesn't the error message precisely tell you whats wrong?

Comment: It will throw error because you are passing `11` arguments while calling the procedure `p_paymententry1`. You should pass only `10` args or add the declaration of 1 more variable in the procedure.

Comment: `VALUES (p_id, p_date, p_2000, p_500, p_200, p_100, p_50, p_20, p_10)`? There are `int` fields and no` varchar` or `char` fields. You should revise your insertion instruction first. So I do not mean `INSERT INTO paymententry_truck (p_id, p_date, p_2000, p_500, p_200, p_100, p_50, p_20, p_10) VALUES ('', '', '2000', '500', '200', '100', '50', '20', '10');` Note that `timestamp` and `date` fields can not be null, so you might want to use a `varchar (39) `.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer

{SET @p0='NULL'; SET @p1='CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'; SET @p2='1'; SET @p3='1'; SET @p4='1'; SET @p5='1'; SET @p6='1'; SET @p7='1'; SET @p8='1'; SET @p9='15,17'; CALL `p_paymententry1`(@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9);}

Comment: That's the same as CALL p_paymententry1 (NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '12', '1','1','1','','','6','15,17');

Comment: Yes and it is working when I am sending value in above answer style

Comment: When I run your code I get ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '15,17' - did you change something? What datatype is trans1.Sr_NO

Comment: trans1.SR_NO is int(11)